# Aucun constructeur sans paramètre défini pour cet objet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this erreur when  i run web application asp.net mvc i get this error in below

> [MissingMethodException: Aucun constructeur sans paramètre défini pour
>   cet objet.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +122
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +239    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Une erreur s'est produite lors de la
>   tentative de création d'un contrôleur de type «
>   PFFClinique.Controllers.AccountController ». Assurez-vous que le
>   contrôleur a un constructeur public sans paramètre.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +188    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +443    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: Critical point: _PFFClinique.Controllers.AccountController ». Assurez-vous que le contrôleur a un constructeur public sans paramètre.]_ Do you have a public constructor for the AccountController without parameters?

Comment: I have constructor by parameter such as public AccountController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

Comment: @steve all the controller of the project have private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public AppointmentsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        } unitofWork how can  i resolved this issue